# I want to log every message from one server to one file but i gets error

Tags: python, file, text, discord.py, bots

I want to log every message from one server to one file but i get error can someone help me please

**Code**

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    async for message in message.channel.history(limit=1):
        file1 = open("MyFile.txt","a")
        file1.write("msg: "+str(message.content)+" " +str(message.channel)+" "+str(message.author))
        file1.close()
```

**Error**

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vikto\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\vikto\OneDrive\Desktop\selfbot\main.py", line 73, in on_message
    file1.write("msg: "+str(message.content)+" " +str(message.channel)+" "+str(message.author))
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 39-40: character maps to <undefined>
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):```
````

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `logging` module with something like?

```py
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(RotatingFileHandler('MyFile.log', maxBytes=1e+7, delay=True))
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    async for message in message.channel.history(limit=1):
        logger.info("msg %s %s %s", message.content, message.channel, message.author)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look's like your charmap codec, you might want to try adding "encoding to utf-8 while opening MyFile.txt

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    async for message in message.channel.history(limit=1):
        file1 = open("MyFile.txt","a", encoding="utf-8")
        file1.write("msg: "+str(message.content)+" " +str(message.channel)+" "+str(message.author)+"\n")
        file1.close()
```

I also suggest you adding a new line at the end, but this is up to you